# Finding the mean per class in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am naively iterating over each and every sample of the dataset. Is there anyway to calculate the mean efficiently ?

```
my_root = '/mini_imagenet_full_size/train/'
Clmean = []
dir_list = os.listdir(my_root)
print(len(dir_list))
miniImagenet_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=my_root, transform=data_transform)
Clmean=torch.zeros([64,3,224,224])
for t,c in miniImagenet_dataset:
   print(c)
   Clmean[c,:,:,:]+=t
   
print(Clmean)
```

Comment: I am finding the sum first but I can find the mean later.

Comment: Since the data is on disk and not in memory, you basically compute the mean as you read the data. I don't suppose you can it any faster. You might consider using a `DataLoader` with additional workers so the disk i/o can be done in parallel (using "workers") to the summation.

Comment: @Shai I was thinking of data loader but might have to use a customized sampler such that for each batch it produces all the samples of a particular class.

Comment: you can have a dataloader with `batch_size=1` and `num_workers >= 1` this way you will not need to change the code, and you will benefit from parallel reading of data thanks to the dataloader.